# Dual space of ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

This question comes to me when I read this paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06049.pdf

Let ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of Lipschitz functions $F$ on $\mathbb R^d$ with $F(0)=0$. Then is ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$ is a Banach
space, with the norm defined as

$$\|F\|:=\sup_{x\neq y\in\mathbb R^d}~ \frac{|F(x)-F(y)|}{|x-y|}.$$

What is the dual space of ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$?

PS: I am not familiar with the related literature, and my apologies if this question is not of research level. The motivation of this question is the following: Denote by $\Lambda\subset {\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$ the subset consisting of functions $F$ of the form

$$F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(v_i\cdot x),\quad \mbox{where } f_i\in {\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R),~ v_i\in\mathbb R^d,~ n\ge 1.$$

I wish to show that $\Lambda$ is dense in ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$. To prove that, I wish to argue by contradiction using the Hahn-Banach theorem, while I do not know the dual space of ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$. Any answers or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: In dimension one, by Rademacher's theorem, we can identify a Lipschitz function $f$ with an a.e. bounded function $f'$, and the Lipschitz norm of $f$ is just the (essential) supremum norm of $f'$. Thus, the dual of $\operatorname{Lip}_0(\mathbb{R})$ is isometrically isomorphic to the dual of $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. In higher dimensions, the description is likely similar, in terms of partial derivatives, but less explicit due to relations between the partial derivatives.

Comment: Precisely, the dual of $\text{Lip}_0(R^n)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the quotient  $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ over  the w* closure in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)^*$  of $S:=\{g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n): \text{div}(g)=0\}\subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)^*$

Comment: So all bounded linear forms on ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$ are of the form $f\mapsto <T,\nabla f>$ for $T\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R^d},\mathbb{R}^d)^*$, the representation being not unique.

Comment: @PietroMajer Thank you very kindly for the answer. Could you please write your answer in detail or provide the related references?

Comment: @PietroMajer Moreover, is there any explicit characterization for $T\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)^*$? It is known that $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R)^*$  is the space of all finitely additive finite signed measures defined on $\mathbb R^d$, which are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, equipped with the total variation norm.

Comment: @PietroMajer Finally back to my original question above, do you think $\Lambda$ is dense in ${\rm Lip}_0(\mathbb R^d)$?

Comment: $(L^\infty(X,\mathbb{R}^d))^*\sim (L^\infty(X,\mathbb{R})^d)^*$ as isometric isomorphism:  giving a linear form on $L^\infty(X,\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the same as giving $d$ linear forms on $L^\infty(X,\mathbb{R})$. Each acts on a coordinate: $f\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^d\langle T_i,f_i\rangle$ .

Comment: As to the other question: I do not have an argument, but I think it is not. Note that you can rephrase equivalently the question in $L^\infty$: Is the subspace of all functions $G\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ of the form
$$G(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(v_i\cdot x)v_i ,\quad \mbox{where } g_i\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb R),~ v_i\in\mathbb R^d,~ n\ge 1.$$
dense in $ L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ wrto the sup norm?

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks for the clarification. Actually these questions are related to one research project, and I think your answers are helpful. If you want, I'd like to mention your comments in our work. Also, I can send you later the draft (according to your wish).

Comment: Thank you, you are welcome; as you like, you're not obliged. As I understand here, if you find an answer useful you could up-vote it or even accept it, because the green color that it takes makes people in better mood, and more inclined to answer to other questions :)

Comment: The following paper might be of interest to you: [M. Cúth, O. R. F. K. Kalenda and P. Kaplický, Isometric representation of Lipschitz-free spaces over convex domains in finite-dimensional spaces, Mathematika 63 (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0025579317000031)